# Is this bedroom wall load bearing?

Tags: framing

I purchased a newly built house in North Alabama and I was able to get pictures of framing before sheetrock was installed. I am wanting to remove 2 walls in a bedroom to make it bigger. The bedroom is directly above the garage. Rafters are 2x6 and span 10 feet. I have tried reaching out to the builder to ask him if these bedroom walls are load-bearing, but he won't get back to me.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I read through another post that gave a guide to help answer if a wall is load-bearing or not. I gave my responses below in **bold**

•   If it's an exterior wall it's almost always load bearing.
**It's not an exterior wall**

•   If the joists are not continuous over the wall (they are cut short and meet on top of the wall) it is definitely load bearing.
**There are no ceiling joists -- only collar ties (see pic below)**

[image]

•   If there is a load bearing wall or beam directly above or below this wall, it is likely load bearing.
**Below this room is a garage, but the exterior wall is not directly below the wall in question**

•    If a joist is running perpendicular to the wall, or happens to fall directly above/below the wall, it can be load bearing.
**Floor I-joists run perpendicular to the wall**

•   If there's a single top plate, the wall most likely isn't load bearing, unless the wall uses deeper studs than 2x4 (such as 2x6).
**Single top plate is used, and wall is framed with 2x4. The knee-wall behind the wall in question has a double top plate (pic below shows double top plate of knee wall behind wall in question)**

[image]

•   Expose the wall over a doorway or pass-through. If it's a solid 2x6 or greater turned vertically going from the jack stud on one side to the other, there's a good chance the wall is load bearing.
**N/A**

Comment: What is the span (horizontal length of the roof rafters?  And what is their dimension, 2x8???

Comment: Good question @steveSh.  If those rafters are 2x8 and only a span of 10-12 ft.  I would be ok with removing the wall.  But we don't have that info.

Comment: The fact that you’re not able to answer this question for yourself suggests you might be wise to contract with a reputable firm to at least consult on the designs for the renovation. Mistakes made during DIY projects could reduce the value if your new home, while well-planned and well-executed projects can add value and avoid unexpected costs and inconvenience.

Comment: Rafters are 2x6 and span 10 feet,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we cannot, for sure, say "Yes", therefore any answer is nothing but an educated guess. The OP needs to consult the architect, builder or a licensed structural engineer to determine, 100% one way or the other. Otherwise, significant structural damage could happen, potentially causing injury or death.

Comment: The biggest indicator in my opinion that it isn't load bearing (assuming it was designed correctly) is the angle on the top of the 2x4s. If it were load bearing, I'd expect there to be some sort of straight cut so the weight is pushing straight down on them. In this configuration it'd be relying  on the nails to hold the 2x4s against the rafters.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not an engineer, however it appears that the wall you want to remove is helping to support the middle of a long run of roof rafters. A beam may be needed for support if the studs are removed.

Another option could be sistering additional 2x6 framing to the existing rafters to reduce load deflection.

You may be able to take your pics to an engineer and get an opinion for a modest fee. I would definitely *not* remove the wall prior to getting a qualified opinion.

Answer (score 7):

Like the other answers here, I have to caveat my answer by saying I am not a structural, or registered professional engineer.  But I have seen enough framing to venture an educated guess.

Those walls are NOT load bearing, IMO.  For one thing, if they were load bearing, they would not be tied into the rafters with a single 2x4 laying on its flat side.

[image]

That construction seems to be just to support the installation of sheetrock.

The knee wall that's further down is what I would expect for a load bearing wall and attachment to the rafters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not a builder but have several houses built.  I don't think you can remove those walls.  The question isn't just load bearing but also bracing for the "rafters"/"joists"

- The roof rafter does not appear to be substantial enough after that "wall".
- There are bits of timber that are tying the rafters to that wall.

Around here, the plans have to be submitted to a local Council or Authority.  I would get the plans and look up the architect/draughts person and then ask them the question.

Comment: The blocking nailed into the top plate of the wall and the rafters are for the sheetrock.

Comment: Upvote for contacting architect or more precisely the engineer they employed / that signed off on the plans.